# Error Message with xref tag in oXygen

Tags: dita

I'm using oXygen 17.1 on a Windows to create a DITA doc. I'm getting an error for an external link using xref. Here's my code that isn't working: Go to LINK COPY.
The code is within in a command within a step. The error msg is vague (DOTJ012F). Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Oops, I see Stackoverflow didn't print the full line of code I typed because I don't know how to type it so that it doesn't translate the "href" reference. Please help me at least type the ref so I can include the full line of code I'm using.

Comment: Your question is too broad, I suggest you to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You can check here what the error message means: 
http://www.dita-ot.org/dev/user-guide/DITA-messages.html

But we do not have enough details to help further, possibly you are not properly setting the "format="html"" and "scope="external"" attributes on the xref.